# Unable to locate other elements after selecting value in Android Date Picker

Tags: android, selenium, datepicker, appium

[image][image]We are automating mobile app with Selenium, Apppium and Java.

In mobile app(Android), selected a date value from Calendar(popup) and clicked on SET button.

After this step, appium become unresponsive and unable to perform any other action and not showing any error message also.
Manually when I perform a action on the app then the app and appium become responsive and the error showing as,

```
Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {stacktrace=NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Date Picker class: android.widget.DatePicker

SET button class: android.widget.ScrollView
```

Shared app code snippet for reference.

Can some one please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: What is the device android version on which you are executing the test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7806) with appium: After dismissing the alert, appium is no longer detecting any of the fields.

**Workarounds :**

1. You can put app in the background and launch again.
   driver.runAppInBackground(5);
2. Get coordinates (x, y) of any element on screen before opening dialog
   interact with dialog (e.g. select elements, close etc.)
   tap by coordinates (x, y) after closing dialog:
   new TouchAction(driver).tap(x, y).perform();

Comment: Thanks, as suggested tapped on the screen with TouchAction coordinates after selecting the date value resolved the issue.